# checking if a table row exists in table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tablelayout

### WHAT I HAVE

I created a table layout where the rows are dynamically added. 
I have 2 editTexts as columns.

### WHAT I WANT

- If a table row's second editText is focused and enter is pressed, then:

  1. If a table row exists below, focus should be set to it's edittext.
  2. If NO table row exists below, table row should be added and then focus set.

I think I need something like:

```
If(tablerow exists below){
  //do the focusing
}
else{
  //add new row
  //do the focusing
}
```

I used a function *addView* to add the rows :

```
public void addView(Context context) {

    int dpConv = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    i = i + 1;
    try {

        txt_itemName[i] = new EditText(context);
        txt_itemName[i].setText("itName");
        txt_itemName[i].requestFocus();


        txt_qty[i] = new EditText(context);
        txt_qty[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
        txt_qty[i].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        txt_qty[i].setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)                                            

        {

                        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){

                                txt_qty[i].clearFocus();

                                //Need to check conditions here
                        }

        return false;
        }
        });

        tb_row[i] = new TableRow(context);
        tb_row[i].addView(txt_itemName[i]);
        tb_row[i].addView(txt_qty[i]);

        tb_lyt.addView(tb_row[i]);
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use a `ListView` for this, instead of the table layout.

Comment: Really? What are pros of using ListView?

Comment: How are you adding TableRows to your TableLayout? Post the code

Comment: OK,  I have posted the code to add table rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. what about if you try this:

```
if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){

    txt_qty[i].clearFocus();

    //Need to check conditions here
    /* I'm assuming that:
          You have the value of i
          You add TableRows ONLY to your TableLayout
    */
    if(tb_lyt.getChildCount() > (i+1)) {
        //If a child exist below
        //Do your focus setting
    }
    else {
        //Add a new Row.
    }
 }
```

Comment: I had thought about that but the problem is that I am adding deletion features for rows and so, I cant rely completely on the value of *i*. Isn't there any way to check if a view exists or not?

Comment: You can use [`tb_lyt.addView(tb_row[i], i)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) and use `tb_lyt.getChildAt(i)` to get the View and see if it is null (meaning doesn't exist). However, It won't differ much from the above code.